# unable to run custom function in python 3.4.3 shell in conda environment

Tags: python

I am running the following function in python 3.4.3 shell in Anaconda environment but it doesn't run. 
Cursor keep blinking at third line

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have an example of how you are using the function in the shell?

Comment: I just try to define the custom function for squaring any value. Eg f(2) should return 4.

Answer (score 1):

Hit return again.  The shell does not know your definition is complete.  Then you will be able to use the function.

```
In [326]: def f(x):
     ...:     return x**2
     ...: 

In [327]: f(9)
Out[327]: 81

In [328]:
```